# Sign in during asking does not preserve question data

Tags: bug, login, draft

I went to post a question using a new browser. I wrote in the question and then saw the login form at the bottom and realised I was not logged in on my account. I clicked Sign in with Google, signed in with my account, and all was well. However when I was sent back to my question, half of it was missing. The tag I had assigned was gone as well.

I feel that a button that throws away user data without warning is pretty bad design. Either all user data should be preserved or a warning given.

As a random aside, I found it weird that only half the question text was missing; it would almost have been more understandable if it was all missing.

Comment: Should you blame caching?

Comment: @Luuklag I would say the lack of caching is to blame here, no?

Comment: I'm sure it's caching's fault somehow.